# does driving over planks damage tires

Tags: tires

If you place two narrow planks of wood on either side of an electric cord on a driveway so cars can drive over the wood without damaging the cord, does it wear out one's tires if you drive over wood planks everyday?

Comment: Make sure the planks don't bounce around.  I can see them moving and pinching the cord and damaging it even more than just rolling over it with a car tire would.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won’t - but it does help to clip the planks together and also to chamfer the leading and trailing edges.

Answer (score 1):

No,tires would not get damaged if you drive it over the wood. But few points to consider :

1. Maintain proper tyre pressure.
2. Do not spin your tires too much if they are stuck that may cause it to          over heat and would damage the threads